# How do I implement local storage feature to enable saving of theme on refresh?

Tags: reactjs, local-storage, themes

I am unable to implement local storage in my theme switcher app, I would really appreciate assistance

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Header from './components/Header';
import Main from './components/Main';
import themes from './utils/themes';

const App = () => {
  const [theme, setTheme] = useState('');

  const handleChange = (selectedTheme) => {
    setTheme(themes[selectedTheme.value]);
  };

  const refCallback = (node) => {
    if (node) {
      theme &&
        Object.keys(theme).forEach((element) => {
          node.style.setProperty(element, theme[element], 'important');
          if (element === 'background-color' || element === 'background') {
            // apply the same background mentioned for theme to the body of the website
            document.body.style.background = theme[element];
          }
        });
    }
  };

  return (
    <div ref={refCallback} className="main-section">
      <Header handleChange={handleChange} />
      <Main />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

As far as I understand, I need to save the original value in Local Storage, and then change it when changing the theme

Answer (score 0):

you can use a function to save localstorage

```js
export const setTheme = (key, value) => {
  localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value));
}

export const getTheme = key => {
  const value = localStorage.getItem(key);

  if (value) {
    return JSON.parse(value);
  }
}
```

This has more steps to make it work globally, for example use [React Context](https://guias.makeitreal.camp/react/context)

Please read:

[Theming and Theme Switching](https://css-tricks.com/theming-and-theme-switching-with-react-and-styled-components/)

[Build a React theme switcher](https://blog.logrocket.com/build-react-theme-switcher-app-styled-components/)

[Material UI theme switcher](https://www.58bits.com/blog/2020/05/27/material-ui-theme-switcher-react)